# Clarification on the azure service administrator role

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Can service administrator elevate it's role to be a global admin in azure? -- We want to restrict service admin to be a GA. If yes, then how can we restrict it to be a GA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets clarify something: A Service Administrator has access  to a **subscription** whereas the global administrator is someone that has administrator permission of an **Azure Active Directory**.

A Service Administrator might be a "normal" user within your Azure AD. He won't be able to elevate its role to a global admin within the Azure AD. Same applies to an global admin of an Azure AD - the global admin might not have any permission to access a subscription / resource.

You probably ask whether it is possible that the Service Administrator can elevate its role to be an **Account Administrator**. The answer is **no**. He can only assign users to the Co-Administrator role and manage services in the Azure Portal.

[Source.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles)

Answer (score 1):

No, service administrator is service administrator. You cant limit his permissions. Can only change.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles